# How to apply the chain rule to a multivariable function that's not strictly defined?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Say I have the function $g(t) = f(4 \sin 2t , 5 \cos 2t)$, how do I find $g'(t)$? More specifically, if the formulaic method of getting $g'(t)$ is deriving the various partial derivatives in this manner,

$\frac{dg}{dx}*\frac{dx}{dt}$+$\frac{dg}{dy}*\frac{dy}{dt}$

how would one find $\frac{dg}{dx}$ or $\frac{dg}{dy}$?

EDIT: As @Arthur stated below, the $\frac{dg}{dx}$ and $\frac{dg}{dy}$ in the formula above should be replaced with $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{df}{dy}$, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is a function of a single variable, so there is no $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$. There is only $\frac{dg}{dt}$.

$f$, on the other hand, is a different story. It is a function of two variables, so the multivariable chain rule applies there.

We have 
$$
g(t)=f(x(t), y(t))\\
x(t)=4\sin 2t\\
y(t)=5\cos 2t
$$
Now differentiating the first line by $t$ on both sides, and using the multivariable chain rule on $f$, we get
$$
\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y)\\
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}\\
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot 8\cos 2t-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot10\sin 2t\\
$$
We can't do any more than that without knowing what the partial derivatives of $f$ are.

Comment: I assumed that there was a method of getting $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{df}{dy}$, respectively, but I guess without a more defined function $f$ it's impossible. Also, thanks for clearing up the derivatives with respect to $g$ and thereabouts.

Comment: Also, I believe that it's supposed to be $\frac{dx}{dt} = 8\cos 2t$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = -10\sin 2t$

Comment: @Sunsprint You're right about $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$; I was a bit too quick there. And yes, without knowing more about $f$ itself, there is nothing more we can do.

Comment: Why write $\frac{df}{dt}$? The function $f$ is a function of two variables. It's not the same function as $g$.

Comment: @littleO You're right. I think it's better now, with $x$ and $y$ specified to be functions of $t$ already.